# Does Azure B2C support Pushed Authorization Request [RFC 9126]?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, par

Could anyone write the steps or share a link to the documentation on how to enable PAR in Azure B2C.

I have been trying to look for documentation or any blog describing how to enable it for the past 24hours.After extensively searching on Google and digging through the microsoft docs. I was unable to find anything.